# how to print non printable address using python

Tags: ida, linux

i have been doin ctf challenge and came across a problem when i have to push the address of a function into eip{instruction pointer} by overflowing the buffer but the main problem here is that the address of the function is 0x401199 and in other to push the address i have to push it in reverse order like \x99\x11\x40\x00 and i have been using python to do so , but the main problem here is that some the these value like \x99 and \x11 are associated with non printable character and i cannot guess any other method to do so please some one with time can clear my request

i hope i explained my query briefly

Answer (score 1):

You're describing encoding a Python int into bytes. In this case, the int is a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Use [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) for this:

```py
>>> struct.pack("<I", 0x401199)
b'\x99\x11@\x00'
```

- `<` means `little endian` (=smallest byte goes first)
- `I` means `unsigned int` (=32-bit on most desktop platforms)

For the reasons you've describing, these bytes cannot generally be converted into a string: `b'\x99\x11@\x00'` is not a valid utf-8 encoding.

For converting bytes into strings, use the [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) module (+`.encode` to convert `bytes` into a Python string)

For example:

```py
>> binascii.b2a_hex(b'\x99\x11@\x00').decode()
'99114000'
```

Comment: thanks for the help but didnot work! i added struck.pack but now python return bytes not str when use struct,pack but cannot concatenate with the padding  i am trying to

Comment: The python str type is for readable text, byte is for binary data.
Your payload needs to meet certain specifications such as having a specific byte length, having some data at specific offset.

Comment: That said, you can convert a byte string to text, and ignore errors by doing:
`b"\x99\x11@\x00".decode(errors="ignore")`